# Symfony 3 - Fosuserbundle Registartion form getBlockPrefix

Tags: php, forms, fosuserbundle, symfony

I read a lot of posts about how override the FOSUserBundle's registration form. I need to change the form inputs names: Exemple:

```
<input type="email" id="fos_user_registration_form_email" name="fos_user_registration_form[email]" required="required">
```

Must be

```
<input type="email" id="user_registration_email" name="user_registration[email]" required="required">
```

I already extended all the file that I need to edit and it works well. For example in my UserBundle\Form\Type\UserRegistrationType I added a text input for my new field called Firstname and it works well.

In general, in Symfony 3, it's sample to edit the form inputs names by the function getBlockPrefix()

But that doesen't work with the FOSUserBundle Registration Form. Why?

I hope can someone help me.

Answer (score 1):

It must be changed in application's config file in path **fos_user > registration > form > name**, yaml example:

```
fos_user:
    registration:
        form:
            name: your_name (or '' to disable block brefix)
```

I am actually curious why user bundle does not respect form prefix getter.

Source: [config reference](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/configuration_reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try override it by using Symfony form component.

Here an exemple of what I'm doing on my side, on `Registration/register.html.twig`

```
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" method="post" id="form-register" class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
    <div class="form-group" id="fos_user_registration_form">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="gi gi-envelope"></i></span>
                {{ form_widget(form.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control input-lg', 'placeholder': 'form.email'|trans } }) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            {{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control input-lg', 'placeholder': 'form.username'|trans } }) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
</form>
```

Comment: In this way I can override class and placeholde attribute, but I need change name and id...